# Regexp_Replace in oracle to remove the invalid characters in an email address

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, email-validation

I am trying to remove the invalid characters in the given email address. I have tried using the below expression to remove the invalid character

```
select regexp_replace('test|_#test-123@test.com','[[:cntrl:]"#|$%]')
from dual
```

Expected result : test_test-123@test.com

the above is working but still I need some help to validate the regexp values. Or do we have any other method to remove the invalid characters using oracle query.

Many Thanks
Anna

Comment: Why do you want to replace illegal characters? Why not just detect illegal characters (`REGEXP_LIKE`)?

Comment: The data is coming from the other system, so while processing the data i need to remove the invalid character and process the same.

Comment: This question really examines the use of reg expressions for the purposes of cleaning up email addresses (php in lieu of sql/plsql), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Comment: I respectfully submit that the source system should be doing the validating and cleansing of the data.  How are these invalid characters being allowed in in the first place?  Could be a symptom of bigger data quality issues.  Once cleaned, how do you know it is a valid address?